# How do I see bluetooth available devices in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, core-bluetooth, xcode9beta6

I wrote code in objective c to see available list of nearest present bluetooth device. But there are not show any devices.I shows my code bellow to see and tell where am I wrong. I use iPhone se for testing which install iOS 11.1 and bluetooth version 4.2. My output is:

> CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off
>
> refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 0
>
> refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
>
> refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0
>
> ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0

CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready

But after that on screen their is not any device shows 
My code is follows to call scan peripheral:

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central

{
switch (central.state) 

{

 case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:

            NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");

            break;

        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:

            NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");

           [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];

            break;

        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:

            NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is resetting");
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
            NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
            NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

so where did I wrong or any setting will do in iPhone?

Comment: Use `LightBlue.app` (available on the AppStore). Does this one see any device? I guess that at least you implemented the didDiscoverPeripheral and that it isn't called? Did you set the delegate correctly?

Comment: You can only discover BLE devices advertising a GATT service. As @larme says, use LightBlue to confirm that there is a BLE peripheral to be discovered.